# FieldComboBox linked to MapLayerCombBox in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I use a `QgsFieldComboBox`  nested with a `QgsMapLayerComboBox` in a custom plugin, and a script that ables to link both combobox.

```py
def change_layers(self):                                           
    self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.clear()
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = [ layer.name() for layer in layers ]
    self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.addItems(layer_list)

def select_layer_fields(self, vlayer):                              
    self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)
    field = self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)

def run(self):
    if self.first_start == True:
                self.first_start = False
                self.dlg = xdr_ImportPhotoDialog()
            vlayer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()                           #new line
            self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)                                     #new line
            self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.layerChanged.connect(self.select_layer_fields2)   #new line
```

In the same script I use several `QgsMapLayerComboBox` and `QgsFieldComboBox` and they also need to be linked together (`QgsMapLayerComboBox_2` with `QgsFieldComboBox_2` .. etc.)

At the moment the only way I found to do the same thing (applying the same function) is to duplicate both function & calls for every couple of Combobox. Could you help me to build ONE function that would be use for every couple of Combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to connect every signal (`layerChanged` for example) to a function. You also don't need to define functions for that.

You can use one line of code for one `QgsMapLayerComboBox` without function. To do this, you should connect `layerChanged` event of `QgsMapLayerComboBox` to `setLayer` function of `QgsFieldComboBox`. You should do that for every pair of `QgsMapLayerComboBox` and `QgsFieldComboBox`.

```
self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox1.layerChanged['QgsMapLayer*'].connect(self.dlg.mFieldComboBox1.setLayer)
self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox2.layerChanged['QgsMapLayer*'].connect(self.dlg.mFieldComboBox2.setLayer)

...

# when you need field
field1 = self.dlg.mFieldComboBox1.currentField()
```

Comment: such simpler, shorter and logical !! thanks !